# Uploadify uploadifySettings error in IE

Tags: jquery-plugins, uploadify

I am using the code for the uploading image using uploadify plugin, Its working fine in Firfox and safari, but not supported in IE

```
$("#uploadify").uploadify({
    'uploader'      :   'scripts/uploadify.swf',
    'script'        :   'scripts/upload_product.php',
    'cancelImg'     :   'images/cancel.png',
    'folder'        :   'ok',
    'queueID'       :   'fileQueue',
    'auto'          :   false,
    'fileDesc'      :   'jksdhjsdf dsjdsfbfd s',
    'fileExt'       :   '*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif',
    'multi'         :   false,
});
```

**On Click on Buuton**
    $('#uploadify').uploadifySettings('folder',inserted_prod_id);
    $('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();

giving the following error in IE

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 26
Char: 6033
Code: 0
URI: http://192.168.0.1/~/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js
```

Is any solution.

Thanks
Amit Battan

Answer (score 1):

```
'multi'         :   false,
```

Should be

```
'multi'         :   false
```