# Validation uploadify

Tags: jquery-plugins, uploadify

I am using jQuery Uploadify to upload files to my site.  How can I tell if a user has selected a file or not?  I tried using the folder object value of the Uploadify object
but its not working for me--it's always the same.  I assume that it was null before it was selected.

How can I tell that a user has selected a file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var selected = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileInput').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',  
        'auto'      : true,  
        'folder'    : '/uploads',
        'onSelect'  : function() { selected = true; },
        'onCancel'  : function() { selected = false; }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you can test if 'selected' is true/false.

Comment: Hi... Thanks a lot...
I have one more problem regarding this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298676/uploadify-uploadifysettings-error-in-ie